# Оптимизация wordpress по PageSpeed

Tags: pagespeed-insights

Сайт использует WordPress. Помогите разобраться, правильно ли я понимаю, по пункту PageSpeed Insight: "Используйте современные форматы изображений" нужно все подключение картинок изменить на расширение webp? Пользуюсь плагином shortpixel (free), но в итоге делает не всё. Как цитата из фильма "Если хочешь сделать что-то хорошо, сделай это сам". Как это можно осуществить самостоятельно без плагинов?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Анализируйте скорость загрузки веб-страниц на мобильные устройства и ресурсы тормозящие эту скорость в реальном времени на бесплатном онлайн инструменте **[WebPage Test](https://www.webpagetest.org/)**, который рекомендует использовать Гугл. Выберите в фильтре наиболее старую модель смартфона. После получения результата теста, щелкните на наиболее медленном Run - Watterfall. Там будут показаны все ресурсы веб-страницы как горизонтальные бары. Наиболее длинные бары являются наиболее тормозящими ресурсами. Щелкайте по бару и анализируйте эти ресурсы.

Сожмите ваши изображения. Для сжатия вы можете использовать бесплатный онлайн инструмент **[ImageOptim](https://imageoptim.com/online)** или более продвинутый **[Compressnow](https://compressnow.com/)**. На последнем инструменте я выбираю обычно 65% сжатия за которыми уже начинается искажение цветов.

Для дальнейшего изучения оптимизации изображений вы можете читать **[статью Гугл для разработчиков о отзывчивых изображениях](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/design-and-ux/responsive/images)**.